# jq reducing stream to an array of all leaf values using input

Tags: input, jq

I want to receive streamed json inputs and reduce them to an array containing the leaf values.

Demo: https://jqplay.org/s/cZxLguJFxv

Please consider

filter:

```
try reduce range(30) as $i ( []; (.+[until(length==2;input)[1]] // error(.))  )
catch empty
```

input:

```json
[
  [
    0,
    0,
    "a"
  ],
  null
]
[
  [
    0,
    0,
    "a"
  ]
]
[
  [
    0,
    1,
    "b"
  ],
  null
]
[
  [
    0,
    1,
    "b"
  ]
]
[
  [
    0,
    1
  ]
]
[
  [
    1
  ],
  0
]
...

output:
empty
```

I expect the output: `[null, null, 0, ...]` but I get empty instead.

I told `reduce` to iterate 30 times but the size of inputs is less than that. I'm expecting it will `empty` those input of length other than 2 and produce an array containing all leaf values.

I don't know how this will behave when there is no more `input` with length 2 left and there are iterations of `reduce` left.

I want to know why my filter returns empty. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `jq -n '[inputs | select(has(1))[1]]'` would produce your expected output.

Comment: thx a lot! but can you do it by fixing my filter (using `input`)?

Comment: Added another one using `reduce` and `inputs`.

Comment: pmf could you explain why my filter returns empty?

Comment: Your construction forces the generation of arrays of a particular length, `30` in this case. As there's only 26 items, it cannot produce a single array of that length, it fails at the 27th iteration (`input` fails => `reduce` fails => `catch empty` is evaluated). Using `26` instead of `30` will work (in this case), and produce one array of that length. Going down to `13` will produce two arrays, and so on. Also note, that you are missing one item (the first `null`) which was read as regular input. If you provide the `-n` option (like I did), it'll be also read using `input` or `inputs`.

Answer (score 1):

These filters should do what you want:

```sh
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $in ([]; if $in | has(1) then . + [$in[1]] else . end)'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/5jSAJAOpmV)

```sh
jq -n '[inputs | select(has(1))[1]]'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/q0IQjUtmS5)